# Ubuntu 18.04: Not able to input any language other than English

Tags: language-support

I have installed Chinese(Simplified) and Japanese. I added both language to input source. I could change to any of the two in the up right corner. Yet when I type, it is still English.

edit:
output:
GLib-GIO-Message: 13:06:11.799: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
@a(ss) []

Comment: Did you adjust your keyboard layout? That might be a separate setting.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output from this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`